# Meaning of Clang warning "-Wsigned-enum-bitfield"

Tags: c++, clang, portability, bit-fields

Please explain to me the meaning of "-Wsigned-enum-bitfield" Clang warning.

In my code I've got a definition of a `struct` with bitfields:

```
struct Options {
    BackgroundType backgroundType : 2;
    LineSpace lineSpace : 2;
    bool letterSpacing : 1;
    bool shadow : 1;
    Qt::AlignmentFlag alignment : 9;
} options;

options.alignment = Qt::AlignLeft;
```

When compiling this code with Clang, I get the following warning:

> enums in the Microsoft ABI are signed integers by default; consider
>   giving the enum `Qt::AlignmentFlag` an unsigned underlying type to make this code
>   portable

Enum `Qt::AlignmentFlag` is external to my code, and I can't change it. I'm inclined to simply ignore this warning. What's the worst that could happen if I leave this code as it is?

Comment: @BoPersson Please provide it as an answer.

Comment: I think the suggested duplicate already indicates that scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the enum uses all the 9 bits, you get a negative number when reading it back. Might give you problems when comparing it to some other value.